# Can I overlay animated gifs with UIImageView on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to overlay an animated gif onto the camera preview on an iPhone with UIImageView.
Currently, following this post: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273 I am able to to so with PNGs.
How can I do this with animated gifs? Specifically, over the live view of the camera?

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView doesn't support animated gifs. Checkout this post on how to deconstruct an animated gif and use it with a UIImageView.

[Link](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/12/making-gif-animating-on-ios.html)

EDIT:

Here is a link to the docs on a camera overlay view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW21

Comment: You need to create a camera overlay view. I'll link to the docs on it.